# windows app page shifts up after I use virtual keyboard

Tags: extjs, cordova, windows-phone-8, shift, virtual-keyboard

I'm using sencha-touch 2.3.1 and cordova 3.4.0.
My app works well in android and ios devices. In windows, app works fine until I have a form in the page and when I select that form, the virtual keyboard is shown. After I'm done using the keyboard and close it, the whole app page seems to shift up a bit and it leaves a gap or horizontal bar at the bottom. 
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Did you add an application Bar to your page ? The description you made makes me think of that..

Comment: Found the solution for my issue:

In the MainPage.xaml, Changed 

shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True" 
to
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False"

It's working properly now.